# My component disappeared from my React Application

Tags: reactjs, react-router, components, ondisappearing

I was making an react application, and used react router. The problem I am facing is that my component is not showing up. I've tried everything nothing seems to work.

Edit: Here's the sandbox of this code: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-currying-gm4gc?file=/src/App.js

I just want the textform component to show up

App.js:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Alert from './components/Alert';
import About from './components/About';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom"
import TextForm from './components/TextForm';


function App() {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("light");
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState(null);

  const showAlert = (message, type, symbolID, directory) => {
    setAlert({
      msg: message,
      type: type,
      symbolID: symbolID,
      directory: directory
    })

    setTimeout(() => {
      setAlert(null);
    }, 2100);
  }

  const toggleMode = () => {
    if(mode === "light"){
      setMode("dark")
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(21 25 30)";  
      document.body.style.color = "white";  // #dadce0
      showAlert("Dark Mode has been Enabled", "success", "check-circle-fill", "M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-3.97-3.03a.75.75 0 0 0-1.08.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-.01-1.05z");
    }
    else {
      setMode("light")
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      document.body.style.color = "black";
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <Navbar title="TakhtiUtils" mode={mode} toggleMode={toggleMode}/>
      <Alert alert={alert}/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/About" component={About}>
          <About/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/" >
          <TextForm mode={mode} showAlert={showAlert} heading="Enter Some Text:"/>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is my TextForm component that is not showing:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

export default function TextForm(props) {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    const upperClick = () => {
        let upperedText = text.toUpperCase();
        setText(upperedText);
        props.showAlert("Text was successfully converted to Uppercase", "success", "check-circle-fill", "M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-3.97-3.03a.75.75 0 0 0-1.08.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-.01-1.05z");
    }

    const lowerClick = () => {
        let loweredText = text.toLowerCase();
        setText(loweredText);
        props.showAlert("Text was successfully converted to Lowercase", "success", "check-circle-fill", "M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-3.97-3.03a.75.75 0 0 0-1.08.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-.01-1.05z");
    }

    const clearClick = () => {
        setText("");
        props.showAlert("Text was cleared!", "danger", "exclamation-triangle-fill", "M8.982 1.566a1.13 1.13 0 0 0-1.96 0L.165 13.233c-.457.778.091 1.767.98 1.767h13.713c.889 0 1.438-.99.98-1.767L8.982 1.566zM8 5c.535 0 .954.462.9.995l-.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 1-1.1 0L7.1 5.995A.905.905 0 0 1 8 5zm.002 6a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z");
    }

    const changeHandle = (event) => {
        setText(event.target.value);
    }

    const capClick = () => {
        let firstChar = text.charAt(0); 
        let newText= firstChar.toUpperCase(); 
        setText(newText+text.slice(1)); 
        props.showAlert("Text was successfully Capitalized", "success", "check-circle-fill", "M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-3.97-3.03a.75.75 0 0 0-1.08.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-.01-1.05z");
    }

    const copyClick = () => {
        let copiedText = document.getElementById("textBox");
        copiedText.select();
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(copiedText.value);
        props.showAlert("Copied to Clipboard", "success", "check-circle-fill", "M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-3.97-3.03a.75.75 0 0 0-1.08.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-.01-1.05z");
    }

    const spacesClick = () => {
        let spacedText = text.split(/[ ]+/);
        setText(spacedText.join(" "));
        props.showAlert("Extra Spaces Removed", "success", "check-circle-fill", "M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-3.97-3.03a.75.75 0 0 0-1.08.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-.01-1.05z");
        
    }

    let wordCount = text.split(" ").length - 1;

    return (
        <>
        <div className="container">
            <h2>{props.heading}</h2>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <textarea className="form-control" id="textBox" rows="8" value={text} onChange={changeHandle} placeholder={"Start Typing..."} style={{backgroundColor: `${props.mode==='dark'?'#0a0a0a':'white'}`, color: `${props.mode==='dark'?'white':'black'}`}}></textarea>
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={upperClick}>Convert To Uppercase</button>
            <button className="btn btn-primary mx-3" onClick={lowerClick}>Convert To Lowercase</button>
            <button className="btn btn-primary " onClick={capClick}>Capitalize Text</button>
            <button className="btn btn-primary mx-3" onClick={copyClick}>Copy Text</button>
            <button className="btn btn-primary " onClick={spacesClick}>Remove Extra Spaces</button>
            <button className="btn btn-danger mx-3" onClick={clearClick}>Clear Text</button>
        </div>
        <div className="container my-2">
            <h1>Text Info</h1>
            <p><strong>{wordCount}</strong> words and <strong>{text.length}</strong> characters</p>
            <p><strong>{(0.008*wordCount)}</strong> Minutes Read</p>

            <h2>Preview</h2>
            <p>{text.length===0?'Nothing to preview here...':text}</p>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

I wanted so when I clicked on the navbar buttons, I could jump to another page. But now, even if I click nothing shows up.
Thank You!

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, for example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox.

Comment: @NishargShah  Here's the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-currying-gm4gc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: please give us the proper example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have doubled the declaration of `About` component inside router, so remove either of them:

```
<Routes>
        <Route path="/About" /*component={About}*/>
          <About/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/" >
          <TextForm mode={mode} showAlert={showAlert} heading="Enter Some Text:"/>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
```

Comment: The problem is with the TextForm component and the about component still doesn't work